# python class variable won't updated in multiprocessing

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, locking

I am using multiprocessing to faster a long process in python and I want to save my data in a separate class in order to make code a little cleaner but it seems that whether I change class var in the process it will roll back to the last state before the process, while in proceed it show that variable is updated.

here is simplified example

```
class state_mangment():
  def __init__(self):
    print('__init__')
    self.last_save = -1

  def update_state(self):
    self.last_save  =self.last_save + 1
    return self.last_save

from multiprocessing import Process, Lock
def f(l, i,persist_state ):
    l.acquire()
    try:

        print('last save is ',persist_state.update_state(),' should be ',i)
    finally:
        l.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = Lock()
    persist_state = state_mangment()
    processes = []

    for num in range(10):
        p = Process(target=f, args=(lock, num,persist_state ))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for p in processes:
      p.join()

    print(persist_state.last_save)
```

here is the output, as you can see increase variable from -1 to 0 as  we can see in return value but it won't start from 0 in next iteration

```
 
__init__
last save is  0  should be  0
last save is  0  should be  1
last save is  0  should be  2
last save is  0  should be  3
last save is  0  should be  4
last save is  0  should be  5
last save is  0  should be  6
last save is  0  should be  7
last save is  0  should be  8
last save is  0  should be  9
-1
```

Comment: You should always specify the version of all relevant software; e.g., the version of python you are using. Specifying the operating system is also always a good idea even when it doesn't seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things wrong with your code. A function run by `multiprocessing.Process()` does not share the address space of the parent process. Which is why the manipulation of the `persist_state` object is not reflected in the parent process. That you can use a `multiprocessing.Lock()` object in this fashion is because that class was designed to work in that fashion when used in a `multiprocessing.Process()` context. That does not mean you can manipulate the state of arbitrary objects and have those manipulations reflected in the parent process.

See this description of the [Manager()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) class for one way to solve this problem.